# Fixing bootloader

Tags: grub, mx-linux

Grub no longer shows up in the boot list.
The only thing which shows up is the Windows boot manager. Only Windows boot manager is listed when running the `efibootmgr` command.

The thing is, the grub installation is still there and works.
When running from a LiveUSB, I can go into the boot rescue tab, search for bootloaders, and it finds the grub bootloader and can boot from it.

From the LiveUSB it shows that Windows boot mgr is at `hd2,1` and grub is at `hd2,2`
When mounting the EFI_System partition it shows four bootloaders: `BOOT`, `Microsoft`, `MX`, `MX23`

So how do I make it boot into grub?

Comment: What brand/model system? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Not sure if tested with your version of Linux, may need to add a utility or two to fully work.